# Simple question about antiderivative?

Tags: calculus

So this has been confusing me a lot. Let $f(x)=x^2$ and let $F(x)=\displaystyle \int_{1}^{x} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$. Then $F(1)=0$, obviously, but the antiderivative of $f$ (which is the same as $\displaystyle \int_{1}^{x} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$) is $F(x)=x^3/3$, so $F(1)=1/3$, not $0$?

What caused the confusion is that I forgot that a function has infinitely many anti derivatives; they are defined in this case as $F(x)=x^3/3 + C$, and in this example $F(x)=x^3/3 -1/3$, $x^3/3$ is just a special antiderivative where $C=0$.

Comment: On one hand, this question accurately represents a very common confusion... One fundamental point is that it is a bad idea to use the same "variable of integration" as a variable that is a "parameter". Also, there is no single anti-derivative, in any case, but infinitely many, by adding any constant. So, depending what you mean exactly, there is no issue at all. (And this was incorrectly tagged as involving analysis, calculus of variations, and stochastic analysis...)

Answer (score 1):

The integral $\int_1^x x^2\,dx$ is equal to 
$$\left.\frac{x^3}{3}\right|_1^x.$$
This is $\frac{1}{3}x^3-\frac{1}{3}$. Note that  $\frac{1}{3}x^3-\frac{1}{3}$ is $0$ at $x=1$, as you pointed out it should be.

**Remark:** When we are finding definite integrals with limits of integration that involve variables, it is best to use a different "dummy" variable of integration. Things may be clearer if you write
$$F(x)=\int_1^x t^2\,dt.$$
While in principle the notation you used is not *wrong*, it is, for good reason, frowned on.

Note also that talking about "the" antiderivative of a function $f(t)$ is not quite right. The function has infinitely many (very closely related) antiderivatives.

Comment: It's quite bad form to have the variable of integration also used as a limit, e.g. $\int_1^x x^2 \, \operatorname{d}\!x$. Wouldn't a "dummy variable" be better?

Comment: I used the notation used by OP, but then made a remark later. It is not only bad form, but a poor idea, and may be part of the reason for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

What your example shows is that the anti-derivative of $\operatorname{f}$ *is not*, in general, given by
$$\int_1^x \operatorname{f}(t) \, \operatorname{d}\!t $$
Take your example, let $\operatorname{f}(x) = x^2$. We know that the anti-derivative if $\tfrac{1}{3}x^3+c$, yet

$$\int_1^x t^2 \, \operatorname{d}\!t = \left[ \tfrac{1}{3}t^3\right]_0^x = \tfrac{1}{3}x^3-\tfrac{1}{3} \equiv \tfrac{1}{3}(x^3-1).$$

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter what C is equal to.

The antiderivative of f is $F(x) = \int _0 ^x f(t) dt = \int _0 ^x t^2 dt = (\frac{t^3}{3} + C) |_0^x = (\frac {x^3}{3}+ C) - (\frac {0^3}{3} +C) = \frac{x^3}{3}$

$\therefore F(1) = \int _0 ^1 f(t) dt = 1/3$

Comment: why is it $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{x} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$ and not $\displaystyle \int_{1}^{x} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiderivative#Uses_and_properties